# ios bluetooth not support tcp/ip protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth

How to make the IOS `bluetooth` support `TCP/IP` protocol;

`CoreBluetooth` only support `BTLE`;

And not found PAN Profile in Bluetooth service of IOS device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HHServices](https://github.com/tolo/HHServices) is a library that emulates what `NSNetService` used to do pre-iOS 5 (and what it still does with a WiFi connection).  Maybe you will have some luck with that.